# Face detection in iOS 5.1 on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios

I have read several places, that iOS 5.1 is supposed to contain an updated version of the camera app that has a face detection feature.

I have updated my iPhone 4S to 5.1, but can't find any such feature.

Am I missing something, or are the rumors/mentions of the face detection false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rumors aren't false, but perhaps misleading. Unlike face detection in, say, iPhoto, this isn't about actually associating a face with a contact you already have (through similar photos), but rather about helping the camera focus on what you'll likely want to have in focus (namely, faces). [Here's](http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/camera.html) Apple's marketing text on it:

> This camera loves a face.
>
> With new face detection, the iSight camera is smart enough to know whether you’re taking a portrait or a group shot. It focuses on the most prominent face in the frame and balances exposure across up to 10 faces. So you’ll definitely catch smiles. And maybe even a smirk or two.

You'll know face detection is working from the green rectangle that appears.

[New to 5.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1504) is that more than one such green "detected face rectangle" may show up:

> Camera face detection now highlights all detected faces

Comment: Does the iPhone 4 have this feature too or it's 4s only?

Comment: The feature appears to be 4S-specific, presumably relying on its new image processor.